# Transcendence of a $q$-series

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $q\ge 2$ be an integer. Fourier's proof of irrationality of $e$ adapts to prove the irrationality of
$$\Psi_q=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k)}$$
Is this number knwon to be transcendental?

Comment: @FedorPetrov From the first sentence I suspect arbitrary integer $q\geq 2$ is allowed.

Comment: Indeed, I missed this

Comment: Don't know how to proceed from this, but $\Psi_q=G(1/q)$, where $G$ is the [Rogers-Ramanujan function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers–Ramanujan_continued_fraction). I believe there is a lot known about the cases when are values of $G$ algebraic numbers.